# I am unable to get the Access token to access the Reddit API

Tags: android, api, reddit

i am trying to get access token to access the user info. following the data filled up in Postman. any help on what i am doing wrong is greatly appreciated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y96q4.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the endpoint doesn't expect JSON, so try to POST x-www-form-urlencoded data instead.
[image]